# fieldChanges lookupFields

Tags: javascript, netsuite, suitescript, clientscript

I trying to learn set up automaticaly using client script lookupField where input at field customer, then the field in the salesman section will change according to record_customer_sales_person.

```
/**
 * @NApiVersion 2.1
 * @NScriptType ClientScript
*/
define(['N/search'], 
    function (search) {

    function fieldChanged(context) {
        var currentRecord = context.currentRecord
        var fieldId = context.fieldId

        if (fieldId != 'customer') return
        
        const id = currentRecord.getValue({ fieldId: 'custrecord_me_customer_name'  })
        if (!id) return
        
        search.lookupFields.promise({
            type : search.Type.record_customer_sales_person,
            id : 60,
            columns : [ 'custrecord_me_customer_name','custrecord_me_join_sales_person' ]
        }).then(function(user) {
            currentRecord.setValue({ fieldId: 'custrecord_me_customer_name', value: user.customer });
            currentRecord.setValue({ fieldId: 'custrecord_me_join_sales_person', value: user.custbody_salesman });
            log.debug({
              details: "test: " + user});
        });
    }

    return {
        fieldChanged: fieldChanged
    }

});
```

I trying this but has not respond( even error notification is not showing). How to fixed this case. Thank you for your helping

Comment: (1) the search type looks off. Is it the native customer field? so search.Type.CUSTOMER? or just 'customer'. If it is a custom record so just put that in a string 'custrecord____'. (2) Why is the id hard coded to 60? I would assume that the id's value is the result of currentRecord.getValue({ fieldId: 'custrecord_me_customer_name'  }) (3) the if (fieldId != 'customer') dose not seem to match the getValue that follows. Just seems off. (4) the result of the lookup is not the full customer record, it is a map of the requested fields values and texts if I am not mistaken (5) just use a debugger;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming this is a custom record?

search.Type.record_customer_sales_person does not exist as a valid Enum value. Here's the list of valid Enum values for [search.Type](https://docs.oracle.com/en/cloud/saas/netsuite/ns-online-help/section_4483165708.html)

Use `customrecord_record_customer_sales_person` instead of `search.Type.record_customer_sales_person`